# How to delegate Resource costs overview on Azure Resource Groups?

Tags: azure, billing, azure-resource-group

We are currently moving our on-premise applications to Azure. Our department received a Resource Group in our companies tenant. We are able to create new resources within the RG, however we are not able to see the associated costs after we created the resource.

Desired result: overview of current resource costs and rate of spending for our department

Currently only the head of internal IT is able to view the spending per department.

[image: Screenshot of Resource costs tab in Resource Group]

Is it possible for the global administrator to delegate the rights for viewing Resource Group costs to a department?

Comment: try resource group contributor permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new role added to Azure, Azure Billing Reader role.

*The new Billing Reader role allows you to delegate access to just billing information with no access to services such as VMs and storage accounts.* [More info.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-billing-reader-role-and-preview-of-invoice-api/)

[image: Billing Reader role; Overview of Subscription]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately， in Resource Access control(IAM), I add all Roles to the user account, and the user account still can't read "Resource costs".

> Is it possible for the global administrator to delegate the rights for
>   viewing Resource Group costs to a department?

If you want to get the right to read the resource group costs, we can specify a **co-administrator** for subscription, in this way, we can read resource costs.
More information about add a co-administrator for subscription, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jason.  
Using the **co-administrator** user role would give us access to way more Resource Groups and functionalities than necessary. This is unacceptable in regards to our security regulations.

Comment: @KoenUbbink  we can't use normal account to see the billing data for now, only the Account Administrator has permission to get to the billing data and usage information. Maybe we can recommend to the global administrator to send you the resource costs every week.

Comment: We will look into connecting Power BI to the Azure billing info. Do you have a content pack available?

Comment: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-azure-enterprise/